# Will AKKA has v2.2.1_2.11.0-M5 compiled version of SBT do, I do not use the SBT has been compiled through

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

LINK：https://github.com/akka/akka/releases

Version：v2.2.1_2.11.0-M5

I have been using SBT compilation error

ERRO：

```
[error] (akka-zeromq/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.
zeromq#zeromq-scala-binding_2.11.0-M5;0.0.7: not found
[error] (akka-channels-experimental/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] (akka-sample-osgi-dining-hakkers-scalaBuff/*:update) sbt.ResolveExceptio
n: unresolved dependency: net.sandrogrzicic#scalabuff-runtime_2.11.0-M5;1.2.0: n
ot found
[error] (akka-cluster/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net
.sandrogrzicic#scalabuff-runtime_2.11.0-M5;1.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: net.sandrogrzicic#scalabuff-compiler_2.11.0-M5;1.
2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed 2013-10-8 10:40:40
```

I need to compile the latest version, and my eclipse sync
My eclipse using the latest version 2.11 scala
How do I resolve。tks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are using akka as a dependency in your build. Could you show your sbt build script to better understand your problem?

Comment: akka-zeromq for 2.11.0-M5 is not released

Comment: If you do not zeromq dependence can rely remove it? I want to compile the latest version of AKKA v2.2.1_2.11.0-M5